# MVC list with a column to display an image

Tags: visual-studio, model-view-controller

I have a schedule for a hobby sports team site I did years ago.  I want to refresh in in VS 2017 using VMC as a learning tool to get better with MVC.

The data for the list presents this as the first column:
 teamLogo = "~/icons/" + tm.logolocation + ".jpg",

In the ASP view, I set the display for image and it works fine.  How do I do similar in MVC?

Thank you for the pointers.

Comment: I have my view with the traditional @Html.DisplayFor( ...)

Comment: How do I render the path that occupies model.logolocation ?

Answer (score 0):

The controller uses this to present path and file extention no ~ needed.

```
 foreach (schedule game in Schedule)
            {
                game.logolocation = "/icons/" + game.logolocation+".jpg";
            }
```

The index view uses this:

```
<td>           
            <img src=@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.logolocation) />
        </td>
```